# "off-topic" post appeal, my post was rude, but not off-topic

Tags: discussion

sorry for posting my appeal here, i didn't find the appeal button in my post or anywhere

spoiler alert: just in case i accidentally offend somebody with how i sound, i'm adding this spoiler to this post as well: the post contains "rude" language cuz i don't know how to be polite, focus on the facts, not on the tone

the topic i made was mistakenly taken as an off-topic or a rant question was not really off-topic

it was rude, but that does not mean it was off-topic or not helpful, it is just that i don't know how to be polite, so my tone sounded like that

it was about parenting, well, not exactly about parenting, but about relationships with abusive parents, sorry for posting the appeal here, but i didn't find where to appeal

i don't know if posting about parents is off-topic now, but if it is, they should remove the parents tag from the possible tags

i didn't find an appeal tag so i put the rules tag, sorry for being disordered and posting the appeal here, i didn't find where to appeal

spoiler alert: rude paragraph {
i have not seen a parenting forum as sensitive as this one, but i need to be patient with adults that take all as an offence, i need to not let my defiance disorder get the better of me
}

that disorder is precicely why i am this good dealing with abusive parents, which is why i used that in a constructive way joining this forum to help people deal with abuse in their households

but if this makes you feel better, i added a spoiler to my other post and in this one, telling adults to not read it if they are easily offended by feedback, and that the purpose of the original post is not to give feedback, but to help others stand up if they have an abusive family

i know that this forum does not welcome feedback, and i respect that boundary

Comment: When you were on your previous account, you were given a lot of guidance, and you were told to make yourself familiar with the [about] and [ask] and [answer] pages. If you still think this is a forum, that indicates you have not read and understood those pages, so please go and read them.

Answer (score 3):

You've made several comments about this *forum*. You've evaluated us as unwelcoming to feedback. Please allow me to point out a few things about those statements.

This site isn't a forum at all. It's kind of the opposite; it's a *Question and Answer* site. Discussions are discouraged. From the help section,

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK.

If you posted a question (E.g. "How should kids react to consequences they find unhelpful or even abusive?"), that's a perfectly acceptable topic. It's a question, it's about a parenting issue, and asks for an answer. The answer to that question should be posted *as an answer*, not within the body of the *question* post.

You've decided we're not interested in feedback. Feedback on this site is given in meta (where your post now resides.) A common problem on some of the slower sites in this network (that I'm aware of) is that we don't get *enough* feedback, that our meta site is too slow. We actually want feedback.

Otherwise your feedback comment doesn't apply to this site, it applies to the parents with whom you've had experience, and as this was your first post, that's not *us*. You have no past experience with us that we know of; this was your first post. You joined two days ago. Don't judge us.

Every site has a culture. When someone unfamiliar with the site's culture submits an off topic post, having it closed down (for the culture's perfectly valid and outlined-in-the-help-section reasons) feels hostile and threatening.

Your action here can be seen as hostile to us. It's as if I walked into your house because the door was opened, sat down, put my feet up on the table and immediately expressed anger that I wasn't fed my favorite meal. That would be  both inappropriate and hostile.

Your feelings (everyone's feelings actually) are valid in that they exist. They happen. They are not right or wrong. You can't control which feelings pop up their heads in a situation. You can only control how you act.

We welcome questions as per our site culture. Familiarizing yourself with the culture will minimize conflicts (and subsequent unpleasant feelings) with it.

Again, for emphasis on why your first post here went sideways: familiarizing yourself with the culture (by reading the help section) will minimize conflicts (and subsequent unpleasant feelings) with it.

It's not personal. We don't know you. You don't know us. We want to reduce drama you have with your parents if we can. That's part of what we're here for. We're here to help *you*, within our framework of doing so.

Sorry this is so long.

<sub>Oppositional Defiant Disorder is really hard. Like, *really, really hard*. If you have this, you also have my sympathy. Life with ODD is a roller coaster for sure, and not the fun kind. It's like the kind of roller coaster that's old and rickety, that hasn't passed inspection for a while, and the guy with his hand on the controls is having a bad day and isn't afraid to show it. It's hard to maintain one's equilibrium when on it. And with ODD, everyone in a position of authority over you is like that guy with his hand on the controls.</sub>

Comment: This is not a new user. Simply a person who didn't like the way the community handled their posts last time and deleted their account before starting again with pretty much the same behaviour.

Comment: @RoryAlsop - Ah, thanks. No way to know that otherwise.

Comment: No worries. Good answer in any case - thanks.